# Twitter, change protected status with PHP

Tags: php, twitter

Can anyone suggest, with examples, how I might go about changing my protected tweet setting from False to True via PHP.

What I'd like to do is Switch my protected tweet status to: `True`, post a update and then switch it back to `False.`

I beleive the URL required is thus:

```
http://twitter.com/account/update_profile.xml

...
<protected>false</protected>
..
```

Bear in mind I am not the greatest at PHP :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I'd like to do is Switch my protected tweet status to: True, post a update and then switch it back to False.

I don't think that is going to do what you want. Protection applies to your **timeline** (that is, all of your tweets), not each particular tweet. If you make your tweets protected, non-followers can't see them, but if you go back to unprotected, they can still everything you posted while you were protected.

Comment: Thanks, least I didnt waste to much time.

Answer (score 0):

POST

> authenticity_token=token you can grab from http://twitter.com/account/settings using DOM or regex
>   user[protected]=1

to http://twitter.com/account/settings