# Twitter protect/unprotect API

Tags: twitter

I am trying to avoid spam accounts that monitor my stream marking all of my tweets (and my followers' replies) as favorites. Since there are a lot of such accounts, blocking and reporting all of them is not an option and I'm trying to create a Twitter client that works as follows:

```
(1) Protect my tweets.
(2) Post a new tweet.
(3) After a few minutes, unprotect my tweets.
```

I wasn't able to find an API that matches my needs however. Are there any internal APIs or alternative means?

I found [Twitter, change protected status with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992520/twitter-change-protected-status-with-php), is it still relevant in 2015?